# Highcharts solid gauge dynamic update

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

My idea is to display CPU and memory load with highcharts solid gauge which would update every few seconds, but what ever I do, it just wont run it as I wanted, so it's like this:

I have this php code which is giving me an integer for cpu and memory usage

```
$cpu = exec("mpstat 1 1 | grep 'all' | awk '{print 100 - $12}' | head -n 1");
$mem = exec("free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $3 / $2 * 100}'");
```

This is my highcharts js script:

```
$(function () {

var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '105%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background3) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                // y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};setTimeout(function () {
$('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: 'CPU'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'CPU',
        data: [0],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:18px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || '#CECECE') + '">{y:.1f} %</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver"></span></div>'
        },
    }]

}));

$('#container-rpm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: 'RAM'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'RAM',
        data: [0],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:20px;font-family:Arial;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || '#CECECE') + '">{y:.1f}%</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver"></span></div>'
        },
    }]

}));
    var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts(),
        point,
        newVal,
        inc;

    if (chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        inc = <?php echo $cpu; ?>;
        newVal = inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }

    chart = $('#container-rpm').highcharts();
    if (chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        inc = <?php echo $mem; ?>;
        newVal = inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 5) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }   }, 5000);});
```

...and this is my container for calling the gauge:

```
<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto" >
<div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
<div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div></div>
```

Now, the problem is when it refreshes, it keeps giving me the same values on every refresh.
Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: You should write a `php` script that returns these values as JSON then make an AJAX call every few seconds.  Right now they are loaded at page load and remain the same until the page is reloaded.

Comment: In addition to Marks comment, you can read information how you can make your chart inside Highcharts docs: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

Comment: @Grzegorz Blachliński thanks for the info, it helped me a lot, I will answer my own question if anyone would need it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the meanwhile I managed to solve my problem with the help of @Grzegorz Blachliński's comment, so here goes:

first, my php code which is nothing more than two variables checking for cpu load and memory usage.

```
<?php
$cpu = exec("mpstat 1 1 | grep 'all' | awk '{print 100 - $12}' | head -n 1");

$mem = exec("free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $3 / $2 * 100}'");

echo "[$cpu,$mem]";?>
```

Now, for some reason `json_encode($cpu,$mem);` was returning values which were inside quotes and I was able to read them as integer with for example `alert(mem);`, but the chart didn't accept those values and didn't draw chart, so I did a workaround for it by echoing the proper format of variable values.

Here's my javascript file:

```
function setDivHeight() {
var div = $('#cpu-meter');
div.height(div.width() * 0.75);
div = $('#memory-meter');
div.height(div.width() * 0.75); } $(function () {

if( $(window).width() < 1000){
    setDivHeight();

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    setDivHeight();        
});

}  


var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        events: {
            load: requestData
        }
    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};

$('#cpu-meter').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: 'CPU Usage'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [0],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:20px;font-family:Arial;color:#777;">{y:.2f} %</span><br/>'
        },
    }]

}));

$('#memory-meter').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: 'Memory Usage'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [0],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:20px;font-family:Arial;color:#777;">{y:.2f} %</span><br/>'
        },
    }]

}));

function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'core/cpu-data.php',
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(load) {
            var chart = $('#cpu-meter').highcharts(),
                point = 0,
                newVal = 0,
                inc = 0;

                point = chart.series[0].points[0];
                inc = load[0];

                diff = newVal - inc;

                if (diff > 0) {
                    newVal = newVal + diff;
                } else {
                    newVal = newVal - diff;
                }

                point.update(newVal);


                chart = $('#memory-meter').highcharts(),
                point = 0,
                newVal = 0,
                inc = 0;

                point = chart.series[0].points[0];
                inc = load[1];

                diff = newVal - inc;

                if (diff > 0) {
                    newVal = newVal + diff;
                } else {
                    newVal = newVal - diff;
                }

                point.update(newVal);

                setTimeout(requestData, 3000);
            },
        cache: false
    });
}});
```

As you can see, ajax is getting data from my php file and making gauge increase and decrease it's value for `setTimeout` value (don't use `setInterval`).

Once again, thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 0):

The chart may be reloading, but it looks like you never reload the `$cpu` and `$mem` variables themselves. They would also need to be refreshed, as once they're assigned, they will continue to hold their initial value until you specifically re-execute their `exec(...)` commands and update them.

Comment: Yes, noticed that, later on I figured out that in my code above, I was adding the variable value to a non-existent value, instead of creating points on each ajax request; thanks, your reply helped me also.